# Saving a custom object using IsloatedStorageSettings

Tags: windows-phone-7, settings, isolatedstorage

I'm trying to save an object in IsolatedStorageSettings to save the high scores for my game, but whenever I try to save an updated copy of the object C# seems to think the object hasn't changed.  I tried creating a custom Equals function for the HighScores class but that doesn't seem to help.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

```
public bool AddOrUpdateValue(string Key, Object value)
{
    bool valueChanged = false;

    // If the key exists
    if (isolatedStore.Contains(Key))
    {
        // If the value has changed
        if (isolatedStore[Key] != value) //This keeps returning false
        {
            // Store the new value
            isolatedStore[Key] = value;
            valueChanged = true;
        }
    }
    // Otherwise create the key.
    else
    {
        isolatedStore.Add(Key, value);
        valueChanged = true;
    }

    return valueChanged;
}



//This is located inside the HighScores class    
public bool Equals(HighScores newHighScores)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < highScores.Length; i++)
    {
        if (!highScores[i].Name.Equals(newHighScores.GetIndex(i).Name))
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (!highScores[i].Time.Equals(newHighScores.GetIndex(i).Time))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't implemented the equality operators '==' and '!=' and these compare reference equality, you are going to have provide the implementation which maps on to your 'Equals' method

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I implemented == and !=.  However it's still not working.  I checked the isolatedStore value just before it ran Save() and it held the correct values. However, those values don't persist when I start the app again.  Any other ideas?

Comment: so you can step through your code and 'AddOrUpdateValue' works as expected?

Comment: Yeah it does. The save command is what seems to be screwed up

Comment: I believe you need to override GetHashCode as well

Comment: he should implement GetHashCode as well, but in this case it will have no affect, the hashcode used is for the key not the value.

Comment: @abhinav - I implemented GetHashCode as well, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Are you sure you're not overwriting it again with old values later in the application?

Comment: you said the value don't persist when you start the app. Is the problem with saving the data (like you said in your first comment above) or comparing the object (like you said in your main question)?

Comment: @Zain - Have you implemented Not-Equals operator with both parameters of type HighScores. If that is the case, your != operator won't work correctly, you need to create it with !=(HighScores h, Object o)

Answer (score 0):

You should do isolatedStore.Save() to commit the changes

Comment: No, that's not the case. I checked the isolatedStore value just before it ran Save() and it held the correct values. However, those values don't persist when I start the app again. Any other ideas?